# Is there a hashmap library for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

In JavaScript, all Objects act a bit like hashmaps.  However, the keys to these hashmaps must be strings.  If they're not, they're converted with `toString()`.  That means:

```
var a = {foo: 1};
var b = {bar: 2};
var o = {};
o[a] = 100;
o[b];              // 100
JSON.stringify(o); // '{"[object Object]":100}'
```

That is, since the `toString()` of any plain Object is `[object Object]`, they all address the same value.

I'd like to create a hashmap where Objects with the same properties and values address the same value, but objects with different properties or values address different values.  That is:

```
var a = {foo: 1};
var b = {bar: 2, baz: 3};
var c = {baz: 3, bar: 2};
var hash = new Hash();
hash.set(a, 100);
hash.get(b);      // undefined
hash.set(b, 200);
hash.get(b);      // 200
hash.get(c);      // 200
```

My first instinct was to use `JSON.stringify()` to turn objects into strings, but:

```
var hash = {};
var b = {bar: 2, baz: 3};
var c = {baz: 3, bar: 2};
hash[JSON.stringify(b)] = 100
hash[JSON.stringify(b)] // 100
hash[JSON.stringify(c)] // undefined
JSON.stringify(b)       // '{"bar":2,"baz":3}'
JSON.stringify(c)       // '{"baz":3,"bar":2}'
```

That is, JSON serialization is order-dependent.

Is there a good library or technique to implement a hashmap like this?

**Update**:

Equivalently, is there a good hashing function such that:

```
hash({foo: 1, bar: 2}) == hash({bar: 2, foo: 1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick proof-of-concept...

I've hardly tested it at all, and I'm certain that there will be corner-cases that it can't deal with.

Performance will be hideously inefficient because the `__createHash` function needs to recurse through the members of any objects and then sort them, in order to generate a "hash" that meets your requirements.

```
HashMap = function() {
    this.get = function(key) {
        var hash = this.__createHash(key);
        return this.__map[hash];
    };

    this.set = function(key, value) {
        var hash = this.__createHash(key);
        this.__map[hash] = value;
    };

    this.__createHash = function(key) {
        switch (typeof key) {
            case 'function':
                return 'function';

            case 'undefined':
                return 'undefined';

            case 'string':
                return '"' + key.replace('"', '""') + '"';

            case 'object':
                if (!key) {
                    return 'null';
                }

                switch (Object.prototype.toString.apply(key)) {
                    case '[object Array]':
                        var elements = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
                            elements.push(this.__createHash(key[i]));
                        }
                        return '[' + elements.join(',') + ']';

                    case '[object Date]':
                        return '#' + key.getUTCFullYear().toString()
                                   + (key.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString()
                                   + key.getUTCDate().toString()
                                   + key.getUTCHours().toString()
                                   + key.getUTCMinutes().toString()
                                   + key.getUTCSeconds().toString() + '#';

                    default:
                        var members = [];
                        for (var m in key) {
                            members.push(m + '=' + this.__createHash(key[m]));
                        }
                        members.sort();
                        return '{' + members.join(',') + '}';
                }

            default:
                return key.toString();
        }
    };

    this.__map = {};
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it needs some work to be perfomant and bullet-proof, but I think you've got the right idea.

Comment: @Peeja: I'm not sure that it can be made performant while still meeting your requirements. Although, depending on your exact needs then perhaps it can be made good enough.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you the [jshashtable](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/index.html) project from  [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down).

Comment: jshashtable is a good start, but it only works when the key is the exact same object.  I want to be able to use a different but equal object (`b` vs. `c` in the code above).  Essentially, I need a library which provides a good definition of equality by properties and values.

Comment: As would I :). In this case, you'd need a custom `equals` function that compares the properties of two objects, either as a method of your objects or, better, passed into the `Hashtable` constructor: `var objectsEqual = function(o1, o2) { for (var i in o1) { if (o1[i] !== o2[i]) { return false; } } for (i in o2) { if (!(i in o1)) { return false; } } return true; }; var hash = new Hashtable(null, objectsEqual);`

Comment: Peeja: jshashtable handles that case when you provide it with your own equality function, as in my comment above (forgive the lack of formatting; comments don't allow any better).

Comment: True, that works.  For the use I have in mind, I really need to use a `hashCode` approach (for performance).  Do you know a good way to hash a JS object by its properties?  That's really the heart of my question.

Comment: I considered this question when deciding whether to try and implement a default hash function for jshashtable. Really, there's no easy way in JavaScript. You could write a function to extract all the properties in an object into an array of key-value pairs, sort it on property name and then JSONify that, but once you're doing all that in your hashing function you may find that it's more efficient not to use it. A compromise could be to have a hashing function that simply concatenates the object's values for one or two properties that vary a lot between your objects.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but ES6 has a feature that may be relevant: `Map`

Maps can have arbitrary objects as keys, and arbitrary values as values.  The main distinction is that the objects used as keys stay unique, even if objects are identical.

Here's an example:

```
var map = new WeakMap();

var o1 = {x: 1};
var o2 = {x: 1};

map.set(o1, 'first object');
map.set(o2, 'second object');

// The keys are unique despite the objects being identical.

map.get(o1); // 'first object'
map.get(o2); // 'second object'
map.get({x: 1}); // undefined
```

`JSON.stringify`ing the objects wouldn't be able to distinguish between `o1` and `o2`.

MDN has [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).  There's also a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) which doesn't maintain references to the objects used as keys, so they may be garbage collected.

The [Traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/GettingStarted) doesn't yet have official polyfills for Map and Weakmap, but there is an open pull request with polyfills for both.  The code for those polyfills (in case anyone wants to add them individually) are here: [Map](https://github.com/DmT021/traceur-compiler/blob/hash-collections/src/runtime/polyfills/Map.js) and [WeakMap](https://github.com/DmT021/traceur-compiler/blob/hash-collections/src/runtime/polyfills/WeakMap.js).  Assuming those polyfills work well, you can start using Map or WeakMap today. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own class with a `toString` that ensures an ordering of keys.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype has Hash quite nicely covered http://prototypejs.org/api/hash

Comment: The Prototype's `Hash` implementation will not work to store an arbitrary object as a key, the OP will have exactly the same results that is having now, check the implementation of the [`set` method](http://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/lang/hash.js#L124) and [this example](http://jsbin.com/imeqa3/edit).

Answer (score 0):

[jOrder](http://github.com/danstocker/jorder) could be modified to treat objects with the same properties (but in different order) as identical when performing an index lookup.

If you have the object `{bar: 2, baz: 3, val: 200}` in your list, and you've previously put a fitting index on a jOrder table like this:

```
var table = jOrder(data)
    .index('signature', ['bar', 'baz'], {grouped: true});
```

Then right now `table.where([{bar: 2, baz: 3}])[0].val` will return 200, but `table.where([{baz: 3, bar: 2}])[0].val` won't.
It wouldn't take much effort though to make it not depend on the order of properties. Let me know if you're interested and I'll push the fix to GitHub as soon as I can.

Comment: FYI I submitted the change. The queries above will both return 200 now.

Answer (score 0):

This thread actually led me to find a bug in my current project. However, this is fixed now and my HashMap implementation in my project (https://github.com/Airblader/jsava) will do exactly what you described. Unlike jshashtable, there are no buckets.

Answer (score -2):

the answer is to use two arrays, one for keys, one for values.

```
var i = keys.indexOf(key)
if (i == -1)
  {keys.push(key); values.push(value)}
else
  {values[i] = value; }
```

Comment: Please don't. You'll have a performance nightmare. Benchmark here: http://people.iola.dk/arj/2012/05/30/hashtables-in-javascript/

Comment: This does not answer the original question, which is about creating hashmaps with object keys.