# Given an object A and a list of objects L, how to find which objects on L are clones of A without testing all cases?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Using JavaScript notation:

```
A = {color:'red',size:8,type:'circle'};

L = [{color:'gray',size:15,type:'square'},
     {color:'pink',size:4,type:'triangle'},
     {color:'red',size:8,type:'circle'},
     {color:'red',size:12,type:'circle'},
     {color:'blue',size:10,type:'rectangle'}];
```

The answer for this case would be 2, because L[2] is identic to A. You could find the answer in O(n) by testing each possibility. What is a representation/algorithm that allows finding that answer faster?

Comment: Note: this is similar to the last question I posted, but is a different (easier, I guess) problem. I thought posting both on the same thread would be confusing so I'm making 2 questions. I hope that is OK.

Comment: Can't you sort L and then do a quick select. O(N*log N) to sort and then O(log N) for finding A. Technically, you aren't testing all cases. This would be good if A can have multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a HashMap and put all objects into the HashMap. Also we would need to define a hash function which is function of data in object (something similar to overriding Object.hashcode() in java)

Suppose given array L is [B, C, D] where B, C and D are objects. Then HashMap would be {B=>1, C=>2, D=>3}. Now suppose D is copy of A. So we would just lookup A in this map and get the answer. Also as suggested by Eric P in comment, we would need to keep the hashmap updated with respect to any change in array L. This also can be done in O(1) for every operation in array L.

Cost of Looking up an object in the HashMap is O(1). So we can achieve O(1) complexity.

Comment: But you have to insert all the items in your list into the HashMap first.  Think about that.

Comment: Inserting into hashmap will be still O(N). But think about a scenario where u have such an array L and u have to look-up objects several times, in that case this approach will be optimal for each look-up.

Comment: You would presumably want to keep the hash map up to date with any changes to the list (or array) you would make; that need not cost substantially more than those list (or array) operations. In other words, you can amortize the cost for maintaining the hash map over the array (or list) operations.

Comment: Also: it seems like the OP wanted to get the index of the identical elements, not the elements themselves. This can still be done with the approach @NirajNawanit suggests; you could map the tuple 'red',8,'circle' to the number 2. You would, however, need to make your hash table use a hash function that uses only the values in the object - not the object itself. In javascript, that can be tricky, as discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3309760/337475

Comment: yes, i just noticed that the answer should be the index. And you are right that we will need to keep the hashmap upto date with any changes in the list.
Regarding hash function, in java we can use a object as a key by overrriding hashcode().
In javascript, it will be tricky and we will need to use a hashmap library and further I am not sure if such a library will be able to support hashing an object using a custom hash function.

Comment: Seems that jshashtable library in javascript can be used to hash even an object and to store them into a hashtable. You need to override custom objectsEqual() method for the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do it faster than `O(n)` with your preconditions.
It's possible to find element in `O(logn)` using binary search, but:

- A) you need elements with one variable to compare
- B) sorted list by that variable

Maybe with some technics (ordering, skip lists, etc.) you can find answer faster than N iterations, but the worst case is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the goal is to find all objects which are clones of A, you must test every object at least once to determine whether it is a clone of A, so the minimum number of tests is N.  Passing through the list once and testing each object performs N tests, so since this method is the minimum number of tests, it is an optimal method.

Answer (score -1):

first, I assume, that you are talking about array, not list. the word 'list' is reserved for specific type of data structures, that has O(n) indexing comlexity, so meantime for any search in it is at least linear.

for unsorted array, the only algorithm is full scan with linear time. However, if array is sorted, you can use binary or interpolating search to get better time.

The problem with sorted arrays is that they have linear insert time. No good. So if you wish to update your set much and both update and search times are important, you should search for optimized container, that in c++ and haskell is called `Set` (`set` template in `set` header and `Data.Set` module in `containers` package respectively). I dunno if there is any in JS.

Comment: A **linked list** is a specific structure, where each node in the list has a reference to the next item in the list. This has O(n) indexing complexity. The term *list* on its own isn't a technical term, and just means something like "a linear sequence of items" without being very specific. Several languages do use the name "list" for an array-like data structure (e.g. Python). Java even has both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, so clearly the list *concept* does not imply "not an array".

Comment: @Ben community disagrees http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type). Though, do not care really.

Comment: If you actually read that very article, it says exactly what I said. *"List data types are often implemented using arrays or linked lists of some sort, but other data structures may be more appropriate for some applications. In some contexts, such as in Lisp programming, the term list may refer specifically to a linked list rather than an array."* In general list does not imply any particular implementation. In some specific contexts, it means linked list, in others it means array.

Comment: @Ben Check part one: indexing is not part of list interface by default. So, it cannot be indexed in constant time via it. ArrayList extends List interface with additional operation, but it is not part of List interfaces, it is an extension. Check part 6 for actual defitintion of List abstract data type.

Comment: @Ben. O(1) indexing in lists may be available as part of specifically optimized implementation, it is not part of list datatype definition and you should never count on it. O(n) indexing, however, is always available.

Comment: @pereakra In some contexts, lists support efficient indexation. Those contexts include Python lists, Java ArrayLists, and **this question** since the OP clearly expects it. That Wikipedia article makes no mention of performance characteristics, and actually **does** say that retrieving the item at a particular index is possible in the next section (which also talks about different implementations having different performance characteristics). Again, I would urge you to actually read what you're linking at me.

Comment: But this is getting a bit silly. To future readers of this answer: it is clearly not the case that the term "list" universally means a linked list to all programmers (case in point: me), but neither can you reliably use it as a generic term for a linear sequence without risk that someone will think you're talking about linked lists (case in point: permeakra).

Comment: @Ben *Abstract datatype* named List has preciesely defined interface (see link) and O(1) indexing is not part of it. Period. Some languages or libraries has entity named List. Reading this entity one expects that they will support same interface. Still, some language designers have chosen to name other entity with this name (see link). It's questionable design decision, but it has been made (see link). Still, the first statement in this comment is true (see link). Are we clear now?